# How to evaluate $I = \int_{\partial B} {x_1}^2 dx$ where $B$ is a sphere in 3D?

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-harmonics

Let $B$ represent a sphere in 3D with radius $R$. I would like to evaluate the following integral
$$
I = \int_{\partial B} {x_1}^2 dx.
$$
That is, each point on the surface of the sphere is represented by the vector $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^\top$, and I want to integrate the square of the first component over the entire sphere. Can this be done analytically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, by symmetry, we can say that all $$\int_{\partial B}{x_i}^2dS(x)$$ are equal ($i=1,2,3$), but their sum is $R^2 vol(\partial B)=4\pi R^4$, so...

Comment: Ok summing them I have $$\int_{\partial B} x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 dx = \int_{\partial B} |x|^2 dx = \int_{\partial B} R^2 dx = 4\pi R^4$$ so the actual integral I'm looking for evaluates to $\frac{4}{3}\pi R^4$? Why do you say their sum is $4\pi R^2$?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I didn't consider the $R^2$ factor. But what I wrote is stiil essentially the answer.